# MultiJson::DecodeError 743: unexpected token while send json data to put request url in poster add on firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, httpwebrequest

I am sending below json data as a param from body of poster

zip='{"zipcode":"501234","cityname":"hyd","countyname" : "Poweshiek","statename" : "Iowa"}'&Accept=application%2Fjson

I am getting error

'

## MultiJson::DecodeError`enter code here`

```
743: unexpected token at 'zip='{"zipcode":"501234","cityname":"hyd","countyname" : "Poweshiek","statename" : "Iowa"}'&Accept=application%2Fjson'
```

`Rails.root: e:/rails/vivadesi`

'
**below is log file:**
'Started PUT "/orgs/updatezip.json?id=4f676eb33e454911a000aea1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-05 07:31:17 +0530
Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents:

MultiJson::DecodeError (743: unexpected token at 'zip='{"zipcode":"501234","cityname":"hyd","countyname" : "Poweshiek","statename" : "Iowa"}'&Accept=application%2Fjson'):

Rendered gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (12.0ms)'

Comment: I am not using any parser,first i need to send json data

Comment: Well then you use standard `multy_json` parser.. try another, say `yajl-ruby` https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby

Answer (score 0):

you're sending by post or get, because giving this error when you try to convert your string to json (the format parameter).

'zip' would be a variable that wanted to get the code.
& Accept = application% 2Fjson can go as parameter in json

example
send json is for test

```
zip='{"zipcode":"501234","cityname":"hyd","countyname" : "Poweshiek","statename" : "Iowa"}'&Accept=application%2Fjson

{"zip":{"zipcode":"501234","cityname":"hyd","countyname" : "Poweshiek","statename" : "Iowa"},"accept":"application%2Fjson"}
```